# Get edge-list / adjacency matrix from feedforward neural net

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network

A feedforward neural net may be seen as a multi-partite graph: the neurones are the nodes / vertices; neurones from layer n are connected to the neurons of layer n + 1.

**Question.** Given a feedforward neural net (for example in Keras), how can easily obtain the edge list / unweighted adjacency matrix of this graph ?

**N.B.:** I need to obtain such graphs because I wan to analyze them (from graph theory perspective). model.summary()  or viz.plot(model) won't do the trick.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to get this in keras and most frameworks, connections are kind of an implicit concept, so its not really explicit

Comment: well actually you could do something with the weight matrices. Can't speak about lstms but for `MLPs` you just need to stack the weight matrices properly. The matrices have weights which are your edge weights and the row index and col index serve as nodes. Just need to stack them properly.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the input.